# unable to right click on Ubuntu Studio xfce

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu Studio `20.04.03` xfce on my Asus `M80VD-EB76` laptop.  I'm liking it so far, except that **I can't get two finger right click to work** like I had on my old ubuntu 18 install.  Two finger scroll does work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

did the trick for me.